# Ubuntu not booting properly. Think nvidia might have something to do with it?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Yesterday I downloaded my first linux distro and it was kind of clunky, wine wouldn't really download properly, "nvidia x server settings" wouldn't open properly and my second monitor was completely dark and wouldn't even show up in display settings. I'm sure atleast some of these things are related to the problem I am facing now.

The problem i'm having now the next day is that when I try to boot up ubuntu (I have dual boot) these lines of code (links below) show up followed by another screen where I see green [ ok ] texts follwed up by what I assume are different systems being confirmed as working properly.

As you can tell I am very new to linux and i'm not sure if I was able to convey my problem coherently, if you have any follow up questions feel free to ask.

Extra info: I use a rtx 2070 nvidia graphics card, my ubuntu version is LTS and if I remember correctly it's version 20.04 or something like that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uckt6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttVGa.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDb1.jpg

Comment: Are you getting grub menu before screens you posted? If so, boot with recovery mode or second line in grub menu. Enable networking & install nVidia driver using terminal. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` When you installed Ubuntu, you have to use Safe boot and choose to install the optional restricted drivers to get the nViidia driver (and any other restricted drivers) installed.

Comment: [1] You need to check what version you are running. 20.04 is old now and you should be trying 22.04 or even 22.10. [2] The message about "recovering journal" means you are just turning it off, not shutting it down properly. [3] Check your motherboard firmware is up-to-date.

Comment: @oldfred Tried running sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in root after booting in recovery mode but after I did that and then tried booting ubuntu in regular mode the problem just seems to have repeated itself with no difference as far as I could tell.  Also tried running sudo apt install [driver-name] but I apparently didn't have enough space for that. Of course tried the autoremove and clean commands but one of them just deleted the previous drivers that got installed by running autoinstall and if I remember correctly one of them wouldn't even run because I apparently didn't have enough space?

Comment: @oldfred Considering all the troubles I seem to be getting would it maybe just be better to do the whole process again and reinstall ubuntu from scratch?. If that's the case how do I remove my current install and what should I do when I reinstall to avoid these issues from occuring again?

Comment: If it takes more than an hour to fix, then reinstall & restore is from backups is best solution. But you must have good backups. With drivers you have to run purge otherwise you create duplicates. Reinstall can easily be done & settings, data & anything else you need can be restored. You do a new install using Something Else install option and choose same / (root) partition as you now have if it is large enough, UEFI install automatically finds & uses the ESP & if swap is a partition will use that, although most installs now use swap file.

Comment: Reinstalled latest version of Ubuntu and overwrote my old broken version. Now i'm having another problem but with grub this time "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported" followed up by some more text and a black backround. Tried looking up some fixes online but if i'm not mistaken they all rely on me actually being able to enter my distro, which I am not able to do because of this error with grub